# Is there any way to generate fingerprint through app in android

Tags: android, unlock, android-fingerprint-api

Is there any way to generate fingerprint through app in android and then use this fingerprint to for authentication. And this fingerprint has no relation with the fingerprint which you use to unlock your phone. If yes then please let me know!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the fingerprint reader is specifically tied to Google Play Service's fingerprint authentication service. You can only use it to verify enrollment of a fingerprint on the device.